# Do I need to use ThreadPoolTaskSupport?

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool

I'm facing a situation in Scala 2.11 where I need a parallel collection to use a specific threading mechanism.  The Scala code depends on a platform written in Java that creates a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) to manage threads; the Scala code needs to hook into the same pool it creates.  From [this doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html), I'll need to set up a `TaskSupport` in the parallel collection.  I can do this by constructing a [`ThreadPoolTaskSupport`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.12/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ThreadPoolTaskSupport) from the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. However, `ThreadPoolTaskSupport` is marked as deprecated (note that `ThreadPoolExecutor` is *not* marked as deprecated in Java).

Is this a case where I just need to use the deprecated Scala class, or is there another way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext`, since a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` and use the `ExecutionContext` to construct an `ExecutionContextTaskSupport`:

```
import scala.collection.parallel. { ExecutionContextTaskSupport, TaskSupport }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

def ectsFromTPE(tpe: ThreadPoolExecutor): TaskSupport =
  new ExecutionContextTaskSupport(
    environment = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(tpe)
  )
```

You can then use the resulting `TaskSupport` like any other:

```
import scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParRange

val nn = ParRange(0, Int.MaxValue, 1, true)
nn.taskSupport = ectsFromTPE(???)
```